# ros::Timer leads to boost::lock_error at process cleanup

Tags: boost, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello again,

in my Program i use different classes with inheritance. Everything works fine until i end the process (Ctrl C).
Then it throws the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost::lock_error
```

The class structure is organized as follows:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| AdditionalObject                                        |
|---------------------------------------------------------|



|---------------------------------------------------------|
| BaseObject                                              |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| boost::shared_ptr<AdditionalObject> m_additional_object |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
                             A
                             |
                             |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| Object                                                  |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

I created a minimal example that reproduces that error:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

// ***************************** class AdditionalObject *****************************
class AdditionalObject
{
public:
  AdditionalObject();

private:
  void timerCallback(const ros::TimerEvent& event);
  ros::NodeHandlePtr m_n;
  ros::Timer  m_timer;
};

AdditionalObject::AdditionalObject()
{
  m_n = boost::shared_ptr<ros::NodeHandle>(new ros::NodeHandle());
  m_timer = m_n->createTimer(ros::Duration(1), &AdditionalObject::timerCallback, this);
}

void AdditionalObject::timerCallback(const ros::TimerEvent &event)
{
  std::cout << "beep" << std::endl;
}

// ******************************* class BaseObject *******************************
class BaseObject
{
public:
  BaseObject(boost::shared_ptr<AdditionalObject> additional_object);

private:
  boost::shared_ptr<AdditionalObject> m_additional_object;
};

BaseObject::BaseObject(boost::shared_ptr<AdditionalObject> additional_object) : m_additional_object(additional_object) { }

// ********************************** class Object **********************************
class Object : public BaseObject
{
public:
  Object(boost::shared_ptr<AdditionalObject> additional_object);
};

Object::Object(boost::shared_ptr<AdditionalObject> additional_object) : BaseObject(additional_object) { }

// **********************************************************************************

// public variables
boost::shared_ptr<Object> object;
boost::shared_ptr<AdditionalObject> additional_object;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "minimal_example");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  additional_object = boost::shared_ptr<AdditionalObject>(new AdditionalObject());
  object = boost::shared_ptr<Object>(new Object(additional_object));

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

I'm using ROS Hydro on Kubuntu 12.04. Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143756/ros::timer-leads-to-boost::lock_error-at-process-cleanup/) by [Blizzard](https://answers.ros.org/users/3189/blizzard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2014-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure why, but if you put

```
  additional_object.reset();
  object.reset();
```

after your ros::spin() the error goes away. Probably you have to unbind before  nodehandle and everything goes out of scope. Making your shared_ptrs local objects also works. I think I'd put them in a class of which the instance goes out of scope before the end of main....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Blizzard](https://answers.ros.org/users/3189/blizzard/) on 2014-03-24**:
Well, learning never stops.
Thank you for your help.